# Простые массивы

Tags: python, массивы

подскажите, пожалуйста, условия задания:
Задан массив `x1, x2, ..., x15`
Определить номер первого отрицательного `xi` и номер последнего отрицательного `xi`.

Что-то в этом духе код:

```py
x = []
for i in range(15):
    print('R[', i, '] =', end=' ')
    x.append(int(input()))
k = 0
while x[k] > 0:
    k += 1
M = 14
while x[k] > 0:
    M -= 1
print(k)
print(M)
```

Выводит неправильный ответ, не понимаю.

Comment: я в пайтоне не шарю, но в строке while x[k] > 0: в скобках квадратных не М случайно должно быть? х[M], а не х[k]

Comment: Благодарю, просто не заметил в упор)

Comment: И проверять нужно `>= 0`, а не `> 0`, иначе у вас на нуле всё закончится, если он есть в данных.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Несколько замечаний. Субъективно, я противник `while` в большинстве случаев.

1. Нет необходимости хранить счетчик, так как есть `enumarate`, который
   возвращает индекс итерируемого элемента
2. Скорей всего `while` лучше заменить на `for` с `break` директивой

```py
arr = [1,2,3,-5,6,7,8,-9,10,11]

result = None
for count, value in enumerate(arr):
    if value < 0:
        result = count
        break
```

3. Чтобы пролистать в обратном порядке можно использовать срез по всему листу с шагом минус один

```py
for count, value in enumerate(arr[::-1]):
....
```

, либо использовать `reversed`

```py
for count, value in enumerate(reversed(arr)):
....
```

Только в данном случае не забыть увеличить индекс на 1 и взять с обратным знаком

Comment: Премного благодарен, лабораторная зачтена)

Comment: @user20271724 на здоровье. Если условие было использовать только `while`, тогда ок. Но обратите внимание, что `while` хорошо использовать когда не известно количество итераций или когда необходим бесконечный цикл с условием выхода. В других случаях лучшее решение будет `for`, вы не выйдете никогда за границы, нет необходимости контролировать длину, нет необходимости иметь внешнюю переменную под счетчик и проч

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не туда reversed воткнул, поправил)